# mistake in mysql statement

Tags: php, mysql

I cant find where my mistake is.

```
    $result= mysql_query(" INSERT INTO inbox ( messages,   from,   to,   date,   control_panel_id,   title )
                       VALUES(  '".$message."'  ,  '".$this->sender."'  ,  '".$this->recipient."', NOW() ,  '".$this->control_panel_id."'  ,  '".$title."'  )
                     ") or die(mysql_error());
```

I get:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from, to, date, control_panel_id, title ) VALUES( ' ' at line 1
```

What am I doing which is wrong?

Comment: `from` is a reserved word. how can you use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`from` is a reserved word in SQL. If that's a column name, you always have to enclose it in backticks. (Or double quotes for ANSI mode).

You could also write your mysql_query string less cumbersome by actually utilizing the double quotes:

```
 $result = mysql_query("
              INSERT INTO inbox
                ( messages,   `from`,   `to`,   `date`,
                 control_panel_id,   title )
              VALUES
                ( '$message', '$this->sender',  '$this->recipient',
                  NOW() ,  '$this->control_panel_id',  '$title' )
           ")
           or die(mysql_error());
```

(And [contemporary](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) PHP database interfaces would be even less effort, bla bla..)

Comment: thanks what is the differnce  between backticks and and co '' pair of single quotes

Comment: Backticks are for identifiers (both column names and table names), while single quotes only enclose string values in SQL.

Answer (score 3):

You need to quote [reserved words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html) like `from` when using them as names or aliases. You can do this by surrounding them with backticks, for example:

```
SELECT messages, `from`, ...
```

If in doubt, you can safely quote all column names.

```
INSERT INTO `inbox`
    (`messages`, `from`, `to`, `date`, `control_panel_id`, `title`)
VALUES
    -- etc...
```

Also, you may wish to consider avoiding names that are reserved worsd in future to avoid problems like this.

Comment: A full list of reserved word can be found here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: @Jona: Thanks. Added the link to my post.

Answer (score 0):

Mysql not suppot some keyword as it used in mysql syntax so i think you have change
keywords from, to and date to other name...